# Does the MYSQL_ROW object have a length?

Tags: c++, mysql

I have been trying to retrieve the length of the results (the total columns) from the MYSQL_ROW object but to no such luck. Is there a way of doing this?

So far I have a hardcoded way of retrieving the first four columns with the following code.

```
while((result = mysql_fetch_row(resource))){
    printf("%s %s %s %s \n",result[0],result[1],result[2],result[3]);
}
```

Whenever I attempt to access any of the values from the result object I am met with a blank suggestion box. I have tried guessing, but this didn't really help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you obtain result with:

```
MYSQL_RES* res = mysql_store_result( conn );
```

or

```
MYSQL_RES* res = mysql_use_result( conn );
```

or

```
MYSQL_RES* res = mysql_stmt_result_metadata( stmt );
```

(depending which interface you use) you can use

```
int unsigned columns = mysql_num_fields( res );
```

to obtain number of columns in sql result.

Answer (score -1):

You get length of affected rows with, `mysql_num_rows($resource)` which will return you integer of afftected rows with your search

Comment: I want the number of columns in a specific row though.

Comment: $resource is php, OP is using C